# PreCalc problem about matrices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 4 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> There exists two nonzero three-dimensional vectors
>   $v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$
>   that are orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$, such that its entries $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers that satisfy $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.
>
> Find either vector.

I tried setting another vector, then subtracting and using the dot product. However, it becomes very ugly very quickly. Is there any other simpler way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you might try using a [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), since that will output the direction of the vector(s) that are orthogonal to both.  From there, try fiddling with the magnitude a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices (at least): The most direct, just write down the matrix equation for your vector $(x,y,z)$ to be orthogonal to the two vectors $a,b$, and then find a non-zero solution, i.e. find a non-zero vector in the kernel of the matrix. You can do this by eliminating one variable from one equation and then letting one remaining variable be a parameter and the other variable given as a multiple of that parameter. Then either of your original equations will tell you how to express the eliminated variable in terms of the parameter as well. The coefficients for each variable as multiples of the parameter will all be rational numbers so you can clear denominators in the coefficients and get an integer vector by setting the parameter to be $1$. Then all you need to do is compute gcd of the 3 integers in your arising solution $(x,y,z)$ and divide by that.

The other way is to use cross product, which works in 3-d, and this will give you an integer vector solution automatically because of definition of cross product and the fact that $a,b$ are integer valued. Then like before, compute the gcd of the 3 integers $(x,y,z)$ in your solution and divide by that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cross-product

$\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}-6 \\ 4 \\ -3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}5\cdot(-3) - 4\cdot(-1) \\ (-6)\cdot(-1)-2\cdot(-3) \\ 2\cdot4-(-6)\cdot5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-15 -(-4) \\ 6-(-6) \\ 8-(-30)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-15+4 \\ 6+6 \\ 8+30\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-11 \\ 12 \\ 38\end{pmatrix}$

This is one solution since gcd(-11,12)=1. Its negative vector is the other solution:

$\begin{pmatrix}-11 \\ 12 \\ 38\end{pmatrix}\times(-1)=\begin{pmatrix}11 \\ -12 \\ -38\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I think you mean $-38$ for either the first or second solution.

Comment: @user2566092: thanx, just corrected it